# Find the input definition

Tags: variable-definitions, assignment, input, information-function

Consider the following definition

```
a = D[x,x]
```

Now, `a=1`.

Is there a way in which I can recover the information about the input definition of `a`, ie is it possible to define a function `info` such that

```
info[a]
(* D[x,x] *)
```

To be more clear, I know that the information is stored, in fact I can recover it typing

```
??In
```

but I'm asking about a way to recover it without manually searching among all the output of `??In` (that seems to me, by the way, a strange output, and I don't know how handle it)

P.S.
Perhaps the question has been asked before, but I cannot find an answer to it

Comment: Have you seen `InString[]`?

Comment: I'm seeing it now, thank you. But I've never used the `RowBox`; so I still struggle with this.

Comment: @Giancarlo You could use [`MakeExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeExpression.html) on the `RowBox`-containing results to translate them to an expression in a standard form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found these functions

-given a symbol `X` it returns the input numbers in which the symbol is present

```
SetAttributes[InNumber, HoldAll]
InNumber[X_] := Union[First/@Position[Table[ToExpression[InString[i]], {i,$Line}],SymbolName[Unevaluated[X]]]]
```

-the following gives the first input in which `X` is present, that is, generally, the definition of `X`

```
SetAttributes[Def, HoldAll]
Def[X_] := DisplayForm@ToExpression[InString[First[InNumber[X]]]]
```

-the following give all the inputs in which `X` is present

```
SetAttributes[DefComplete, HoldAll]
DefComplete[X_] := TableForm[Drop[DisplayForm/@Flatten[{{"In[" <> ToString[#] <> "]:=",ToExpression[InString[#]], ""}&/@InNumber[X]}], -3]]
```

They work in all my cases.

For example

```
a = D[x, x];
b = D[x^2, x];
c[x_] = D[x^3, x];
d[x_] := x
d[{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}] := a d - c b

Def[a] (* a=D[x,x]; *)
Def[b] (* b=D[x^2,x]; *)
Def[c] (* c[x_] = D[x^3, x]; *)
Def[d] (* d[x_]:=x *)
DefComplete[d]
(* In[10]:=
d[x_]:=x

In[11]:=
d[{a_,b_},{c_,d_}]:=a d-c b

In[15]:=
Def[d] *)

DefComplete[x]
(* In[7]:=
a=D[x,x];

In[8]:=
b=D[x^2,x];

In[9]:=
c[x_]=D[x^3,x];

In[10]:=
d[x_]:=x *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work for you. The idea here is to automate a search of the down-values of `In` for a given variable.

```
SetAttributes[defFromIn, HoldFirst]
defFromIn[var_Symbol] :=
  With[{dv = Most[DownValues[In]]},
    Extract[
      dv, ReplacePart[Position[dv, Unevaluated[var]][[1]], -1 -> 2], HoldForm]]

a = D[x, x];
b = D[x^2, x];
c = D[x^3, x];
```

Now

```
defFromIn[a]
```

gives

[image: result_a]

and

```
defFromIn[c]
```

gives

[image: result_c]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply; I've found another way that seems more general: in fact, your function doesn't work in cases such as `f[x_]=x`. Also if I didn't ask for this kind of definition, I think that my solution is more general since it covers also these cases.